# Android app not executed . Please help me out from this problem

Tags: android-studio, data-binding

During Rebuild Project following error message shown in Logcat

Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug FAILED
no info log is passed. There are no resources?

Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug'.

> Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --rerun-tasks
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Os after using this command this message showing bash: ./gradlew: Permission denied

Comment: Run the command from your project's directory. There should be a file called "gradlew". If you are using Windows, the file is "gradlew.bat".
if the command returns BUILD FAILED don't worry try to re-run your project maybe it will run